# Showing web page rather than just URL in ArcGIS Online pop-up box?

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, web-mapping

How can I show an actual web page (rather than just a hyperlink) in the pop-up box of ArcGIS Online?

In the ArcGIS Online "Pop-up Contents" section adding a url in the "Custom Attribute Display" just shows a link, and clicking on it opens the url in different page.

Is there any way to show the web page directly in the map pop-up like happens for images or charts when we click on a layer, as in the mockup below?

[image]

Comment: I am not clear about what you are asking but I think you may be referring to the HTML Popups of ArcGIS for Desktop in its ArcMap application. Would you be able to edit your question to include more precise details and perhaps some pictures to clarify it, please?

Comment: I have posted a picture to make the question clear.

Comment: Thanks - but the main thing I am unclear about is whether you are using ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcGIS Online or some other part of the ArcGIS Platform to display that pop-up.

Comment: Its not desktop, its ArcGIS online, I thought webmap means the ArcGIS online.

Comment: It was your [tag:arcmap] tag that caused me the confusion because that is an application of ArcGIS for Desktop.  I will remove that and your [tag:arcgis-10.1] tag, and replace them with [tag:arcgis-online].

Comment: @fean could you clarify your screenshot - is this showing the behaviour that you'd like to emulate in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: The screenshot I have added is not real, its created by me. I was trying to display a sample webpage(wikipedia) in the pop-up box. The screenshot is basically what I want to emulate. @Stephen Lead.

Comment: It IS possible! I still don't know how... CHART agency in Maryland did it with their [traffic cameras](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=http://services.arcgis.com/7ww0md22RA7aTw3W/ArcGIS/rest/services/Traffic_Cameras/FeatureServer/0&source=sd) (see the IFRAME_LINK column)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the answer above the HTML  tag is not allowed in the custom attribute editor. However if you write the  tag and the {url} to a field of the feature layer it will be executed by the popup.

[image]

I did it by using ArcGIS Online's field calculator and adding the  and it's attributes to each row.

Comment: I dont think this works, i tried and it failed it just shows the value as text

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the clarifications in the comments above. As I understand it, you are creating a map by logging into ArcGIS Online, choosing My Content, then Create Map. From here you are adding a layer using Add , and trying to configure the layer's popup to show a website's *contents*, rather than just a hyperlink to the website's *address*.

I don't believe this is possible using the built-in ArcGIS Online map viewer. The viewer allows you to configure a few options for a popup:

[image]

...but these don't seem to allow HTML. In order to display the contents of the website, you'll need to include it within an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), and this doesn't appear to be supported by the popup - in my testing, the HTML code is rendered as text, instead of being executed:

[image]

If I'm correct, then you'll need to write your own map viewer (rather than using the out-of-the-box ArcGIS Online map viewer) using the [ArcGIS Server JavaScript API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/), which does support running HTML within a popup.